# tkinter Enter and Leave Bindings

Tags: python, tkinter, button, enter

So the problem I am facing is with the "Enter" and "Leave" bind things. It works for hovering which is great but it also fire when the button is clicked which messes up my system which I have.

My system is that when being hovered over the images move up to show they are being highlighted and then when you click them they are selected.

The trouble is that when you click them it fires the "Enter" bind which causes the whole system to mess up. This is not ideal and is even more strange since I have already set the buttons "command".

Scouting for some solutions to this troubling issue thanks!

```
from tkinter import *

Activated = None

def command(self):
  global Activated
  if not Activated:
    Activated = self
  else:
    Activated = None
    Leave(self)
  return

def Enter(self, *args):
  global Activated
  if not Activated: 
    width = self.winfo_width()
    
    x = self.winfo_x()
    y = self.winfo_y() - 1 / 2 * width
  
    self.place(x = x, y = y)
  return

def Leave(self, *args):
  global Activated
  if not Activated: 
    width = self.winfo_width()
    
    x = self.winfo_x()
    y = self.winfo_y() + 1 / 2 * width
  
    self.place(x = x, y = y)
  return

window = Tk()

window.geometry("1024x768")
window.configure(bg = "#1e1e1e")
canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#1e1e1e",
    height = 768,
    width = 1024,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge")
canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)

Rockimg = PhotoImage(file = f"Rock.png")
Rock = Button(
    command = lambda: command(Rock),
    bg = "#1e1e1e",
    image = Rockimg,
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    activebackground = "#1e1e1e",
    relief = "flat")
Rock.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: Enter(Rock))
Rock.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: Leave(Rock))

Rock.place(
    x = 46, y = 441,
    width = 286,
    height = 490.5)

Paperimg = PhotoImage(file = f"Paper.png")
Paper = Button(
    command = lambda: command(Paper),
    bg = "#1e1e1e",
    image = Paperimg,
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    activebackground = "#1e1e1e",
    relief = "flat")
Paper.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: Enter(Paper))
Paper.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: Leave(Paper))

Paper.place(
    x = 363, y = 316,
    width = 297,
    height = 678)

Scissorsimg = PhotoImage(file = f"Scissors.png")
Scissors = Button(
    command = lambda: command(Scissors),
    bg = "#1e1e1e",
    image = Scissorsimg,
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    activebackground = "#1e1e1e",
    relief = "flat")
Scissors.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: Enter(Scissors))
Scissors.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: Leave(Scissors))

Scissors.place(
    x = 721, y = 300,
    width = 256,
    height = 702)

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I reproduced your problem correctly, I guess it should be something like this:

- You hover over a random image and it goes up when your mouse is on it and goes down when you leave it
- When you click the image and leave the image doesn't go down which messes up things later

You might be thinking its the problem with the `<Enter>` binding here because you think clicking it executed it again and when you left the button it stays up but that's not the problem. The problem is that the `Activated` variable is changed to `self` in the `command` function. So if you go to the `Leave` function you'll see that moving widget stuff is under an **if statement**. So now that the `Activated` variable is something that "stuff" does NOT get executed. So the step here is to remove those if statements. However there's another problem and I don't know why you did it, but you have called the `Leave` function under `else` in the `command` function. This will obviously make the widget go down twice. This code below works:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

Activated = None

def command(self):

  global Activated
  if not Activated:
    Activated = self
  else:
    Activated = None
  
  return

def Enter(self, *args):

  global Activated
  width = self.winfo_width()
  
  x = self.winfo_x()
  y = self.winfo_y() - 1 / 2 * width
  
  self.place(x = x, y = y)
  return

def Leave(self, *args):
  global Activated
  width = self.winfo_width()
  
  x = self.winfo_x()
  y = self.winfo_y() + 1 / 2 * width
  
  self.place(x = x, y = y)
  return

window = Tk()

window.geometry("1024x768")
window.configure(bg = "#1e1e1e")
canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#1e1e1e",
    height = 768,
    width = 1024,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge")
canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)

Rockimg = Image.open(f"Rock.png")
Rockimg = Rockimg.resize((200, 200))
Rock = Button(
    command = lambda: command(Rock),
    bg = "#1e1e1e",
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Rockimg),
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    activebackground = "#1e1e1e",
    relief = "flat")
Rock.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: Enter(Rock))
Rock.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: Leave(Rock))

Rock.place(
    x = 46, y = 441,
    width = 286,
    height = 490.5)

Paperimg = PhotoImage(file = f"Paper.png")
Paper = Button(
    command = lambda: command(Paper),
    bg = "#1e1e1e",
    image = Paperimg,
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    activebackground = "#1e1e1e",
    relief = "flat")
Paper.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: Enter(Paper))
Paper.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: Leave(Paper))

Paper.place(
    x = 363, y = 316,
    width = 297,
    height = 678)

Scissorsimg = PhotoImage(file = f"Scissors.png")
Scissors = Button(
    command = lambda: command(Scissors),
    bg = "#1e1e1e",
    image = Scissorsimg,
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    activebackground = "#1e1e1e",
    relief = "flat")
Scissors.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: Enter(Scissors))
Scissors.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: Leave(Scissors))

Scissors.place(
    x = 721, y = 300,
    width = 256,
    height = 702)

#window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```